# Adding Search Bar Location in OnMapClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add a search feature locations via maps with my previous code below.
I've been using the method Geocoder but still experiencing problems.
sorry if my english is not good.

This is my Code .

```
private GoogleMap gmap;
Marker gpin = null;

..........
try {
            gmap = ((NiceSupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            gmap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {


                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                    // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (gpin != null) {
                        gpin.remove();
                    }
                    gpin = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).icon(
                            BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin)));
                    lat = point.latitude + "";
                    lng = point.longitude + "";
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

And This SS:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuxcF.jpg)

Comment: To clarify: You want to be able to search for a location on the map, and place a Marker there?

Comment: Yes Like This Link http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/google-maps-android-api-adding-search-bar-part-3.html 
but I also want to be able to get the coordinates if the maps in touch .

Comment: I would try using the Google Place Autocomplete widget for search. Instead of the Geocoder (I never worked with the Geocoder before). https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: I'm Newbie in Java Android -_- ..